# I cannot produce an error message with division when dividing by 0 (Javascript Calculator)

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, divide-by-zero

To preface this, I'm a beginner who's attempting to create a calculator in Javascript. I currently have a switch statement containing math operators. My issue is that in the switch statement, I want to include an error message (string) where division is concerned when trying to divide by 0; however, no matter what I do, I always get infinity up in the calculator's 'display.'

Any amount of help is greatly appreciated, even if it means me having to re-do this whole thing. Here is a snippet of the function(s) doing the actual calculation (though it is in a class, I will edit in the whole block of code if requested).

```
selectedOperation(operation) {
        if (this.currentDisplay === '') return;
        if (this.prevDisplay !== '') {
            this.calculate();
        }
        this.operation = operation;
        this.prevDisplay = this.currentDisplay;
        this.currentDisplay = '';
}

calculate() {
        let calculation;
        const previousNum = parseFloat(this.prevDisplay);
        const currentNum = parseFloat(this.currentDisplay);
        if (isNaN(previousNum) || isNaN(currentNum)) return;
        
        switch (this.operation) {
            case '+' : 
            calculation = previousNum + currentNum
            break;
        case '-' : 
            calculation = previousNum - currentNum
            break;
        case 'x' : 
            calculation = previousNum * currentNum
            break;
        case '÷' : 
            calculation = previousNum / currentNum
            if (currentNum === 0) return "error";
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }

        this.currentDisplay = calculation;
        this.operation = undefined;
        this.prevDisplay = '';
}

**EDIT**:

getDisplayNumber(number) {
        const stringNumber = number.toString();
        const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split('.')[0]);
        const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split('.')[1];
        let integerDisplay
        if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
            integerDisplay = '';
        } else {
            integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString('en', {maximumFractionDigits: 0 });
        }
        if (decimalDigits != null) {
            return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`;
        } return integerDisplay;
    }

updateDisplay() {
        this.cdisplay.innerText = 
        this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentDisplay);
        if(this.operation != null) {
            this.display.innerText = 
                `${this.prevDisplay} ${this.operation}`;

        } else {
            this.display.innerText = '';
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should consider validating `currentNum` before attempting the operation. Perhaps this previous answer will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8072323/best-way-to-prevent-handle-divide-by-0-in-javascript

Comment: it doesn't seem like you are capturing the return, rather, just calling `calculate()` in `selectedOperation()`.  store returned value in a variable and check it(?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the updated solution. Check the explanation in the comments.

BTW the first argument passed to `addEvenListener` callback is an `event`, not the button itself but you can access the button using `event.target`.

```js
class Calculator {
  constructor(display, cdisplay) {
    this.display = display;
    this.cdisplay = cdisplay;
    this.clear();
  }

  clear() {
    this.currentDisplay = "";
    this.prevDisplay = "";
    // new property error
    this.error = "";
    this.operation = undefined;
  }

  del() {
    this.currentDisplay = this.currentDisplay.toString().slice(0, -1);
  }

  appendNumber(number) {
    // if an error exists and the user try to start a new operation
    // clear everything
    if (this.error) {
      this.clear();
    }
    if (number === "." && this.currentDisplay.includes(".")) return;
    this.currentDisplay = this.currentDisplay.toString() + number.toString();
  }

  selectedOperation(operation) {
    if (this.currentDisplay === "") return;
    if (this.prevDisplay !== "") {
      this.calculate();
    }
    this.operation = operation;
    this.prevDisplay = this.currentDisplay;
    this.currentDisplay = "";
  }

  calculate() {
    let calculation;
    const previousNum = parseFloat(this.prevDisplay);
    const currentNum = parseFloat(this.currentDisplay);
    if (isNaN(previousNum) || isNaN(currentNum)) return;

    switch (this.operation) {
      case "+":
        calculation = previousNum + currentNum;
        break;
      case "-":
        calculation = previousNum - currentNum;
        break;
      case "x":
        calculation = previousNum * currentNum;
        break;
      case "÷":
        // if the user divide by 0 set this.error
        if (currentNum === 0) this.error = "Can't divide by zero";
        // else calculate normally
        else calculation = previousNum / currentNum;
        break;
      default:
        return;
    }

    this.currentDisplay = calculation;
    this.operation = undefined;
    this.prevDisplay = "";
  }

  getDisplayNumber(number) {
    const stringNumber = number.toString();
    const integerDigits = parseFloat(stringNumber.split(".")[0]);
    const decimalDigits = stringNumber.split(".")[1];
    let integerDisplay;
    if (isNaN(integerDigits)) {
      integerDisplay = "";
    } else {
      integerDisplay = integerDigits.toLocaleString("en", {
        maximumFractionDigits: 0
      });
    }
    if (decimalDigits != null) {
      return `${integerDisplay}.${decimalDigits}`;
    }
    return integerDisplay;
  }

  updateDisplay() {
    // if there is an error display the error and return
    if (this.error) {
      this.display.innerText = this.error;
      return;
    }
    this.cdisplay.innerText = this.getDisplayNumber(this.currentDisplay);
    if (this.operation != null) {
      this.display.innerText = `${this.prevDisplay} ${this.operation}`;
    } else {
      this.display.innerText = "";
    }
  }
}

const cdisplay = document.querySelector("#cdisplay");
const display = document.querySelector("#display");
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".numbers");
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".operation");
const equalsButton = document.querySelector("#equals");
const delButton = document.querySelector("#del");
const clearButton = document.querySelector("#clear");
const negButton = document.querySelector("#neg");

const calculator = new Calculator(display, cdisplay);

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});

operationButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    calculator.selectedOperation(button.innerText);
    calculator.updateDisplay();
  });
});

// this agrument passed to the callback function is an event not button
equalsButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
  calculator.calculate();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});
// this agrument passed to the callback function is an event not button
clearButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
  calculator.clear();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});
// this agrument passed to the callback function is an event not button
delButton.addEventListener("click", event => {
  calculator.del();
  calculator.updateDisplay();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it, the solution you gave does provide an error message; however, there seems to be a weird interaction going on with the display function. The error message only shows up after I choose another operator. On the calculator "screen", it would then display: "Can't divide by zero +" for example if I chose '+', it does the same for all of the other operators as well. I've added the display function above if you'd like to see it.

Comment: Can you post all your code or share it in Codepen or something so that I can help you better.

Comment: Yes of course, here's the link: https://codepen.io/superboy20/pen/eYJrVLN